# regex to remove characters between semicolon and period mark

Tags: python, regex

how can I write a regex to remove the words coming after semicolon until it gets to the first period mark?

for instance:

```
try to be nice; underastand people. start fresh.
```

I want to remove "understand people" and have something like

```
try to be nice. start fresh
```

this is my regex but sadly it does not work:

```
sentence = ''.join(re.sub(r';.*?.', '.', sentence))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you user your regex? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: You forgot to escape the dot. `r';.*?\.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape the dot: `r';.*?\.'`. Also, there is no need to `join` anything here, you pass a string to `re.sub` and you get a string after.

A `r';[^.]+'` regex seems better though as it will match a `;` and 1+ chars other than a literal dot (so, you can replace with an empty string):

```
import re
sentence = "try to be nice; underastand people. start fresh."
sentence = re.sub(r';[^.]+', '', sentence)
print(sentence)
# => try to be nice. start fresh.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/V0zHF2)